# How to set value of jQuery TreeSelect programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I set the value of jQuery [TreeSelect](https://github.com/travist/jquery.treeselect.js) from JavaScript when it is populated? Is there something like `$('#treeId').treeSelect('setValue', 3)`? I cannot find in the docs included.

Comment: As far as I can see from the source, there's no concept of each node having a "value".   What are you expecting to see / to happen when you set this?

Comment: I want to set the value by `key`

Comment: Sorry, my point was: what's "value" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since treeSelect is using fancytree, you can use this command:

```
$('#fancytree_container').fancytree('getTree').getNodeByKey(key).toggleSelected();
```